# Why would an express server with passport and express session work fine locally, but not even send a 'set-cookie' response when deployed?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm building a backend for an app I am working on and I am trying to set up authentication with the `passport-magic-login` strategy. I have everything working perfectly on localhost, with the session writing to the db (mongo) and the user is correctly added to the req object. However, when I try and do it from a server in this case Railway, it fails. The response on the callback url doesn't even seem to send a set-cookie header.

### App.ts

```js
// db setup above

const corsConfig: CorsOptions = {
  origin: "https://api.productiondomain.co.uk",
  credentials: true,
};

// enable cors
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// session

app.use(
  session({
    name: "session",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "secret in here",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoDBStore({
      uri: MONGO_URL,
      collection: "sessions",
    }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
      httpOnly: true,
    },
  })
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  console.log("Serializing user", user);
  process.nextTick(function () {
    done(null, { _id: user._id, email: user.email });
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(async function (sessionUser: User, done) {
  const user = await Users.findOne({ email: sessionUser.email });
  console.log("Deserializing user", user);
  process.nextTick(function () {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport magic login
passport.use(magicLogin);

app.use("/user/login", magicLogin.send);
app.get("/user/callback", passport.authenticate("magiclogin"));
```

### Strategy

```js
export const magicLogin = new MagicLoginStrategy({
  secret: process.env.MAGIC_LINK_SECRET || "",
  callbackUrl: "/user/callback",
  sendMagicLink: async (destination, href) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" || process.env.SKIP_EMAIL) {
      console.log("Magic link:", "http://localhost:3000" + href);
    } else {
      sendEmail({
        to: destination,
        subject: "Your magic login link",
        from: "onboarding@productiondomain.co.uk",
        react: `Click this link to finish logging in: https://api.productiondomain.co.uk${href}`,
      });
    }
  },
  verify: async (payload, callback) => {
    console.log("Verify payload", payload);
    try {
      let user = await Users.findOne({ email: payload.destination });

      if (user) {
        callback(null, user);
      } else {
        const newUser = await Users.create({
          email: payload.destination,
        });
        callback(null, newUser);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
  },
});
```